# What is the difference between "hooking" and "rooting"?

Tags: android, rootkits

My client did a pentest and he gave us feedback about root detection.

So I used RootBeer android lib to fix root detection. In their [readme](https://github.com/scottyab/rootbeer#disclaimer-and-limitations), they highlighted that root detection is a "game of cat and mouse".

Once we have delivered the new release with root detection our client gave us feedback that he could break root detection using frida. But IMHO this is hooking not rooting.

I will be happy if someone could give me an explanation about the difference between hooking and rooting and if there is a relationship between them.

Comment: My understanding is that rooting involves obtaining administrative access to the device.  Hooking involves interception of different calls.  This could be either system calls or function calls.  IMO, whether or not using frida counts as hooking as opposed to rooting is moot.  The client wants the "issue" corrected.   My approach would be to advise the client that you can certainly try to fix the issue, but that this will become a cat and mouse game which will require constant updates as new bypasses are found, and confirm that they want to accept the cost of needing to patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rooting is a term for gaining root privileges on a system. Detecting an attacker that has rooted your system is very difficult, since the root user can *generally* do anything it wants, including tampering with logs or modifying security software and configuration. Rooting is a very broad term and can encompass many things. An attacker who rooted a system may use hooking to hide his presence.

Hooking is a specific technique that is often used in hacking (although also has a place in debugging). It usually entails replacing a target function with a "dummy" function that acts as a wrapper and contains code that evaluates or modifies arguments before passing them on to the "original" function, or even replaces the original function in its entirety. Below is example source code for a shared object that hooks a function from the fictional library `libexample` called `is_password_correct()`. If the password is `ActivateBackdoor!` then normal password checks are bypassed and it returns true.

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <string.h>

bool is_password_correct(char *pass)
{
    static bool (*original_function)(char *);
    void *handle;

    if (!original_function) {
        handle = dlopen("/usr/lib/libexample.so", RTLD_LAZY|RTLD_LOCAL);
        original_function = dlsym(handle, "is_password_correct");
        dlclose(handle);
    }

    return strcmp(pass, "ActivateBackdoor!") ? original_function(pass) : true;
}
```

This is not the only kind of function hooking. You can hook other APIs [like syscalls](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/210898/106285) as well.

Comment: I can conclued that there is no relationship between the two concepts ?

Comment: @Chulo Other than the fact that both are terms in hacking, they're unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting Wikipedia:

> In computer programming, the term hooking covers a range of techniques used to alter or augment the behaviour of an operating system, of applications, or of other software components by intercepting function calls or messages or events passed between software components. Code that handles such intercepted function calls, events or messages is called a hook.

So, your client just bypassed your root detection functionality by hooking that specific function with frida and changing the return value of it.
Rooting usually involves obtaining root privileges on a system, not on a function or a library.

Comment: Your is kinda sorta not clear."Rooting usually involves obtaining root privileges on a system, not on a function or a library." what does that mean?